# Locking user's account

Tags: php, html, account

I am trying to figure out how to lock a user's account after X many failed attempts of trying to login. I know I need a counter for how many failed attempts. Here is my pseudocode so far for this task:

```
    int i=0;
    when login fails{
      i++; }
    if(i == 3) {
      lock account for 3 minutes; }
```

Here are my two questions:

-How do I lock the user's account?

-How do I lock the user out for 3 minutes and not allow them to just refresh the page and get 3 more attempts?

Comment: store the count and the date\time in a db

Comment: or store them in a cookie

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to store the time in which you block the user in the `users` table of you Database for the current user.

Then, on load of any page page on your site, you should check this field in the database and compare it with the current time. If the difference is bigger than 3 minutes, then you could remove the "blocked user" flag from the database and set the user as not blocked.

Comment: I use a similar method to this, but don't use a blocked user flag.  You can write a sql to count how many bad logons there have been from a given user since the last good logon, in a given time.  If this is more than the acceptable number of fails then logon is not granted.

Comment: It can be accomplish in different ways. What is relevant here is to save the time in which the user was blocked and use the same field, or another one, to check whether the user is blocked or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could use sessions for that:

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['LOGIN_ATTEMPTS'], $_SESSION['LAST_LOGIN_ATTEMPT'])){
   $_SESSION['LOGIN_ATTEMPTS'] = 0 ;
   $_SESSION['LAST_LOGIN_ATTEMPT'] = null ;
}

if (isset($_POST['login'])){
  $_SESSION['LOGIN_ATTEMPTS'] += 1 ;
  $_SESSION['LAST_LOGIN_ATTEMPT'] = time("now") ;
}
```

Comment: not reliable, any one attempting brute force will be resetting cookies, to wipe the session

Comment: Nothing is reliable. You could also change IP, use proxy, switch browser.

Comment: And if you are going to block some account, the one true user will never log in.

Comment: I wouldn't be able to block a user's account forever. After 3 minutes the counter would have to go back to 0 and they get 3 more attempts.